# Waterfall Dialog not executes all steps when called from other Dialog

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, waterfall

I'm building a bot connected to LUIS to get intents and with some dialogs that make other things.

I have the following dialogs:

- MainDialog: that calls LUIS to get intents
- DialogOne: with some steps
- DialogTwo: with some steps
- ScoreDialog: with a survey to get opinion from user after other dialogs. this dialog can be called from others.

`MainDialog` is the entry point and this is the code:

```cs
public class MainDialog : ComponentDialog
{
    public MainDialog() : base($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.main")
    {
        var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            RedirectStepAsync
        };

        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.main", waterfallSteps));

        AddDialog(new DialogOne($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.dialogOne"));
        AddDialog(new DialogTwo($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.dialogTwo"));

        InitialDialogId = $"{nameof(MainDialog)}.main";
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> RedirectStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext waterfallStepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await waterfallStepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync("What you want?");

        var result = await _myLuisService.RecognizeAsync(waterfallStepContext.Context, cancellationToken);
         
        var topIntent = result.GetTopScoringIntent();

        switch (topIntent.intent)
        {
            case "None": break;
            case "IntentOne": 
                await waterfallStepContext.BeginDialogAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.dialogOne", null, cancellationToken);
            break;
            case "IntentTwo": 
                await waterfallStepContext.BeginDialogAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.dialogTwo", null, cancellationToken);
            break;
        }

        return await waterfallStepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Note that `MainDialog` only has one step that calls to LUIS in order to get user intent.

When user intent is received I switch to another specific dialog with 'BeginDialogAsync' method

For example, we are switching to `DialogOne`.

This is the code:

```cs
public class DialogOne : ComponentDialog
{
    public DialogOne(string dialogId) : base(dialogId)
    {
        var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            StepOne,
            StepTwo,
            StepThree
        };

        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog($"{nameof(DialogOne)}.main", waterfallSteps));

        AddDialog(new TextPrompt($"{nameof(ScoreDialog)}.score"));

        InitialDialogId = $"{nameof(DialogOne)}.main";
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> StepOne(WaterfallStepContext waterfallStepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // do something...
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> StepTwo(WaterfallStepContext waterfallStepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // do something...
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> StepThree(WaterfallStepContext waterfallStepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await waterfallStepContext.BeginDialogAsync($"{nameof(DialogOne)}.score", null, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

This `DialogOne` contains some steps, and when I finish, I want to show a new one dialog to ask their opinion about the process. It's a voting process.

Note that I'm using

```
await waterfallStepContext.BeginDialogAsync($"{nameof(DialogOne)}.score", null, cancellationToken);
```

to call `ScoreDialog`.

Finally, the `ScoreDialog` prompt two options to vote and then, in the next steps we capture and process the response, we thank the user for their vote...

```cs
public class ScoreDialog : ComponentDialog
{
    public ScoreDialog(string dialogId) : base(dialogId)
    {
        var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            AskForScoreStepAsync,
            GratitudeForScoreStepAsync
        };

        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog($"{nameof(ScoreDialog)}.main", waterfallSteps));

        AddDialog(new TextPrompt($"{nameof(ScoreDialog)}.ask"));

        InitialDialogId = $"{nameof(ScoreDialog)}.main";
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> AskForScoreStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext waterfallStepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await SaveConversationAsync(waterfallStepContext, data);

        return await waterfallStepContext.PromptAsync(
            $"{nameof(ScoreDialog)}.ask",
            new PromptOptions()
            {
                Prompt = CreateScoreButtons()
            },
            cancellationToken);
    }

    private Activity CreateScoreButtons()
    {
        var reply = MessageFactory.Text(string.Empty);
        
        reply.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
        {
            Actions = new List<CardAction>()
            {
                new() { Title = "I like", Value = "I like", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack },
                new() { Title = "I dislike", Value = "I like", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack },
            }
        };

        return reply;
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> GratitudeForScoreStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext waterfallStepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await waterfallStepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync("Thanks for voting!");
        
        //TODO: do something with the vote

        return await waterfallStepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
    } 
}
```

But, the issue is when I redirect to `ScoreDialog`, this dialog only shows the first step (`AskForScoreStepAsync`), but does not continue to the last step (`AskForScoreStepAsync`).

What is does is return to `MainDialog` with the value "*I like*" or "*I dislike*" from previous step... this "*I like*" or "*I dislike*" text is passed again to **LUIS** with wrong result (because isn't a valid utterance)

So, what's wrong?

How can I redirect the control from dialog to another dialog, and on this new one dialog, complete all steps?